# Buen día. Saben de alguna librería para recrear la animación de las imágenes al hacer scroll de la página: https://jant.fr/

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen, scroll

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer scroll la imagen tiene una deformación como olas. Quiero recrear ese efecto, saben alguna